# Replacing the box with a harmonic oscillator and finding the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian, time-evolution

I'm trying to strengthen my knowledge of quantum mechanics in general. Given a normalized free particle in a box eigenfunction **as an initial condition**:

$$\psi(x,0) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin(\pi x)& 0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

How can I find $\psi(x,t)$ such that:

$$\psi(x,t) = e^{-i\hat{H}t}\psi(x,0)$$

where:

$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

in the position basis?

Comment: This Hamiltonian is the one describing a harmonic oscillator. So, your problem reduces to the Harmonic oscillator problem, but whose initial states are given by sine functions, no?

Comment: Yes this is it.

Comment: So, you already have the solutions, you simply must make them behave like a sine function at $t=0$ if this is possible... This is my guess, I hope I do not miss anything